# How can I enable the button in kivy which is disabled before?

Tags: button, kivy

:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            source: "bbbg.png"
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

```
    Button: 
        #pos_hint: {'center': .01} 
        #size_hint_x: 1
        #size_hint_y: 0.07 
        #size_hint_x: 0.07
        disabled:True
        pos_hint: {'center': 0} 
        background_color: 1,1,1,0
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'select_next'
        on_press: app.nextbtn(self)
        source: None
        name:""
        Image:
            size: 540, 540              
            center: self.parent.center
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "playbutton.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the button, and then simply set the disabled property to False. For instance, if it is your root widget, you could do `App.get_running_app().root.disabled = False`.

The best way to get a reference depends entirely on the context, provide more information if it's not clear.

Comment: This is one of the screen in my application. When i enter this screen I am playing few sound files periodically and I want to enable one button on this screen for going to next screen after playing all the sound files. So I want to enable that button after playing all sound files.

Comment: I think, In the nextbtn() I should use  self.selectscreen_next.ids.fb.disabled = True

Comment: I think, In the nextbtn() I should use  self.selectscreen_next.ids.fb.disabled = True. Because I added self.selectscreen_next = SelectScreen_next(name="select_next")
self.sm.add_widget(self.selectscreen_next) to the widget. And fb is the id of the button. Please correct me if I am wrong. By the way I the code is not working, I think..I am doing some mistake.