# How can I lock the button for 3 seconds in kivy python?

Tags: python, kivy

I designed a gui. That gui includes button when button pressed it countsdown from 3 to 0 and captures a frame. While in this 3 secs when I press button more then once it captures more then one frame how can i solve this problem waiting your recommendations??

```
   def capturecountdown(self, *args):
  if self.countdown == 3:
     self.mainscr.add_widget(self.counter3_button)
     print("3")
  elif self.countdown == 2:
     self.mainscr.remove_widget(self.counter3_button)
     self.mainscr.add_widget(self.counter2_button)
     print("2")
  elif self.countdown == 1:
     self.mainscr.remove_widget(self.counter2_button)
     self.mainscr.add_widget(self.counter1_button)
     print("1")
  elif self.countdown == 0:
     self.mainscr.remove_widget(self.counter1_button)
     self.countdown = 3
     self.capturepressed = True
     return self.capture()
  self.countdown -= 1
  Clock.schedule_once(self.capturecountdown, 1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409884/4425643

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable the button in kivy which is disabled before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409449/how-can-i-enable-the-button-in-kivy-which-is-disabled-before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the `Button` during the countdown by setting the `disabled` attribute of the `Button`:

```
  def capturecountdown(self, *args):
      self.button.disabled = True   # disable the button
      if self.countdown == 3:
         self.mainscr.add_widget(self.counter3_button)
         print("3")
      elif self.countdown == 2:
         self.mainscr.remove_widget(self.counter3_button)
         self.mainscr.add_widget(self.counter2_button)
         print("2")
      elif self.countdown == 1:
         self.mainscr.remove_widget(self.counter2_button)
         self.mainscr.add_widget(self.counter1_button)
         print("1")
      elif self.countdown == 0:
         self.mainscr.remove_widget(self.counter1_button)
         self.countdown = 3
         self.capturepressed = True
         self.button.disabled = False   # re-enable the button
         return self.capture()
      self.countdown -= 1
      Clock.schedule_once(self.capturecountdown, 1)
```